# Android Toast.makeText error while building

Tags: android

```
error: no suitable method found for makeText(<anonymous OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>>,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>> cannot be converted to Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>> cannot be converted to Context)
```

Comment: You're passing an `<anonymous OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>>` (whatever that is) as a first argument to `Toast.makeText()` which, as the error message explains, requires a `Context` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `makeText()` method is definded as:

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

apparently you are using a listener as a context.

Use instead:

```
Toast.makeText([ACTIVIY NAME].this, "Message...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if you are inside an `Activity` you can use `getApplicationContext()` to get the context

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if you are inside a `Fragment` you can use `getActivity()` to get the context

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Message...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```